# Pagination in Popup LOVs in jQuery mobile Oracle Apex 5 applications doesn't work

Tags: jquery-mobile, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

When requesting the next set of rows, the following source code is generated by Apex and just hangs when the user hits the "Next" button:

```
input type="button" name value="Next" onclick="performAction('NEXT', 11);"
```

Does anyone have a work-around for this problem?

This was reported as a bug in 2013: [Oracle Technology Network discussion](https://community.oracle.com/message/10886935/)

Answer (score 1):

Caught same issue in current version of APEX (5.0.3) and was really disappointed.

But solution is really simple:

go to **Shared Components -> Templates -> Edit Popup List of Values Template**
and remove text

```
</div><br />
```

from **Search Field -> After Field Text**.